# SSL with EclipseLink JPA

Tags: java, jpa, ssl, eclipselink

Is it possible to make JPA use SSL for it's connections. I don't know very much about JPA, so I can't provide many details about what version and provider I'm using, but here is a stripped version of my persistence.xml file. Is there a property you can add that makes it use secure connections?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
<persistence-unit name="MY_PERSISTENCE_UNIT" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <!-- declare class entities here -->

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://URL_TO_SERVER" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="USERNAME" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="PASSWORD" />

        <!-- Optimize database writes to use batching. -->
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC" />

        <!-- Avoids flush being triggered before every query execution. -->
        <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode"
            value="COMMIT" />

        <!-- Configure connection pool. -->
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.connections.initial" value="1" />
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.connections.min" value="64" />
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.connections.max" value="64" />

        <!-- Timeout for connection. -->
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.timeout" value="10" />

        <!-- Configure cache size. -->
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="1000" />

        <!-- Configure database to be created on startup if not already existing.-->
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />

        <!-- Configure simple SQL logging for demonstration. -->
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="false" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="false" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="false" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not anything JPA specific, just about adding arguments to JDBC connection String. Assuming that everything else is correctly set, then adding this should be enough:

```
?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true
```

If SSL connection in general is not working, then this page provides more information: [MySQL 20.3.4.5. Connecting Securely Using SSL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html)

Comment: Thanks! That information looks very promising to get this working. Do I have to set these properties in java code before initializing the DB connection (using System.setProperty) or can I set the properties in the persistence.xml file in the question post (using <property name= javax.net.ssl.....)?

Comment: Note that I don't directly work with the JDBC connection String (JPA handles this, that is why it's seems JPA specific to me)

Comment: Does not make too much difference, parameters can be added to value of javax.persistence.jdbc.url

Answer (score 0):

I found this was useful in EclipseLink 2.5.0 to pass properties through to the JDBC driver:

```
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.property.my_property_name" value="my_value" />
```

This is driver specific, but in your case it would be:

```
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.property.useSSL" value="true" />
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.property.requireSSL" value="true" />
```

Comment: How do you pass in trustSTore information in here ?